# MVC 5.2 How to set default value for datetime-local?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

```
 @Html.EditorFor(m => m.DateOfAcception, new
                {
                    htmlAttributes = new { type = "datetime-local", required = "required" },
                    @class = "form-control datepicker",
                    @value = DateTime.Now.ToString()
                })
```

I got something like that but the Value is not working also my model is

```
public DateTime DateOfAcception { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
```

But i cant get it to start with default value.

This is how it looks in html

[image]

The part Novo is just  `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.DateOfAcception)`
if the left side part can start with that value like that somehow

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use TextBoxFor and put international time and then Razor will convert it to local date time. I hope this will answer your question.

```
  @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.DateOfAcception, "{0:yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss}", new
                       {
                           @class = "form-control",
                           required = "required",
                           @type = "datetime-local"
                       })
```